# Problems install protobuf using cmake

Tags: python, c++, windows, cmake, protocol-buffers

I have been trying to install `imposm.parser`, that drove me crazy. After days online, I managed to install it on mac. 
However, I have been trying to install it on windows, but before that, it is required to install google's `protobuf`.
This is also not going easy at all. I managed to progress a bit, but now I am stuck at this point when nothing is helping. 
The instructions I'm following are here: 
[CMake Configuration](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/cmake#cmake-configuration)
 
 
I have been tryin through cmd, cygwin and Developer Command Prompt for VS2015, with no hope. 
The output is as follows:

**Developer Command Prompt - VS2015**

> [ 53%] Built target lite-test 
>   [ 54%] Linking CXX executable tests.exe
>   LINK: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1.0\VC\bin\link.exe /nologo @CMakeFiles\tests.dir\objects1.rsp /out:tests.exe /implib:tests.lib /pdb:C:\work\protobuf\cmake\build\release\tests.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:X86 /INCREMENTAL:NO /subsystem:console libprotoc.lib libprotobuf.lib gmock_main.lib  
>   
>   C:\Users\Philip\Anaconda2\Library\lib\z.lib gmock.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:tests.exe.manifest" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
>   libprotobuf.lib(gzip_stream.cc.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _deflate referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall google::protobuf::io::GzipOutputStream::Close(void)" (?Close@GzipOutputStream@io@protobuf@google@@QAE_NXZ)
>   
>   
>   …… 
>   
>   
>   ……
>   
>   
>   C:\Users\Philip\Anaconda2\Library\lib\z.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
>   tests.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'C:\Users\Philip\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\cmake\data\bin\cmake.exe' : return code '0xffffffff'
>   Stop. 
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
>   Stop. 
>   NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
>   Stop.

My question is: How to solve this problem? And, is there an easier way to install `protobuf` and `imposm.parser` on windows?

Answer (score 1):

`_deflate` sounds like a function from some compression library. Indeed it is used in a class called `GzipOutputStream`. Are you using the link flags for all dependencies of protobuf?

There is also a machine type mismatch. Maybe you are trying to link 32bit libraries into a 64 bit executable.

Comment: Denes `Are you using the link flags for all dependencies of protobuf?` actually I am not using or changing anything specifically (I'm not that knowledgeable about this), just trying to install `protobuf` by following the instructions on the page I mentioned ..

Comment: You'are configuring a x86 protobuf build cf `/machine:X86` while you Anaconda2 must be be 64bit. Whih generator did you use for CMake ?
`Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64`
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/blob/master/Help/generator/Visual%20Studio%2015%202017.rst
Also you must use a x86-64 Native command prompt or source some env.bat
https://www.appveyor.com/docs/lang/cpp/#visual-studio-2015